# Websockets not working on at least one machine

Tags: javascript, websocket, glassfish, java-websocket

I have an application that uses websockets.
Web server is glassfish 4.1.1 and we are using @ServerEndpoint for the websockets implementation on a server side.

In all computers everything worked fine up to the date, when on one laptop of some customer we got an error (he uses Google Chrome):

> failed to execute 'send' on websocket: Still in CONNECTING state

At that computer this error appears permanently, blocking every functionality that concerns websockets.

We do not setup specific port for websockets. So I assume they are using default one - 80. Other pages loaded successfully (so, our website is accessible from that laptop).

Do you have any key of where to dig? Why only one laptop fails?
Is it needed to provide more information?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be many things:

- Firewall
- Anti-virus
- Chrome flag (like running: chrome.exe --disable-web-sockets)
- Virus/malware
- Man-in-the-middle (MitM)

I suggest to install Firefox. If Firefox has no issues there, then Chrome surely has issues.

Comment: Can firewall or anti-virus block websockets even if they work with 80-th port? I cannot install on that machine everything that I can. Is there some workaround? Probably to replace websockets?

Comment: Some anti-virus filter content from port 80, even blocking or closing your socket. Well, if you want to replace websockets, change your code to use the Comet technique.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It seems that problem is acutally in proxy. Websockets cannot connect behind the proxy. I've found it using http://websocketstest.com/ on that machine.

Comment: I see, well, if the proxy is messing with the packets, we could say it is a kind of Man-in-the-middle. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check what is the port that you try to connect from frontend app (your socket has to be asigned to a port). My WS server was listening on PORT 8080 and some users had outgoing port blocked. I made a proxy from 80 to 8080 and now all users have access.